# Correct place to add Bing Ajax Map Controls in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

All,

I require Bing Maps and its location APIs for plotting geolocation data as pushpins on its map.

More info on Bing Maps here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx

This will be displayed on my single page app, using Backbone.js

This will essentially work like so:

```
initalise bing maps on the page
receive data from another model
plot that data on the map layer
listen for events from ui
```

To me this sounds like a candidate for a model, however this functionality is changing the view (layer) directly. Which seems to go against the principle of a view in Backbone that observes changes in a model, it is not controlled by the model.

Any recommendations where I should put this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "initalise bing maps on the page" - in the view's render (or if using Marionette onRender) method.
2. This is ideally a model provided to the view when initializing, e.g. new MyView({model: myModel}); and you listenTo some events on this model.
3. Calling some Bing API from the view in the event handlers that handle model changes.
4. Listening to UI events is the core view responsibility.